# Java -Unable to access some events code with error

Tags: java, netbeans

I have java form working in NetBeans nicely in the past 
 but now am unable to access to some event codes or seems the form was corrupted with following error message 
stating that my textbox focus gained code not avail or accessible and
when trying in design time to selected said place it gave me no actions
i mean not transfer me to code area from design area only i can
access when action performed code for my form controls ?

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: jTsaleitemNoFocusGained
>     at Inventory.FRMsale$5.focusGained(FRMsale.java:288)    at
>   java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.focusGained(AWTEventMulticaster.java:220)
>     at java.awt.Component.processFocusEvent(Component.java:6422)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6289)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)

The error place in the code is as follows and its the same for all the form controls like textbox, buttons etc

```
public void focusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
           jTsaleitemNoFocusGained(evt);
         }
```

Comment: please post the relevant code and the full stack trace

Comment: yes i gave more info hope it will help you to assist

Comment: please also post the code for function `jTsaleitemNoFocusGained(evt)`

Comment: I cant enter to the said code when i pressed it from design and i made manual search in code by find fuctions but looks the code hidden somewhere or deleted but the problem as it's still bold in the events controls when i click on it to re-write the code it give no repond to move me to code erea

Comment: Your error stack trace simply states that the code cannot be compiled as it contains an error of unrecognised function `jTsaleitemNoFocusGained(evt)`. 
So you require to rewrite the function again.

Comment: why i cant access the function code area when i press same event